# Display two values from two different columns into one textbox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to display two values from two different tables in one in textbox in relation to a particular institution.

The code that I wrote is not displaying the "advisor_name" and only displaying "Influence_weight_name". And I also want both names to be displayed on one line, so the end product should look something like this: Advisor Name - Weight Name

Can anyone help?

Below is my code:

```
Dim totalRecords As Integer = sqlTableInstitution.Rows.Count
            Dim advisorText As String = ""
            Dim weightText As String = ""

            If IsDBNull(sqlTableInstitution.Rows(0)("advisor_name")) <> True Then
                advisorText = sqlTableInstitution.Rows(0)("advisor_name")
            End If

            If IsDBNull(sqlTableInstitution.Rows(0)("Influence_weight_name")) <> True    Then
            weightText = weightText & "-" & sqlTableInstitution.Rows(0)("Influence_weight_name")
           End If
Textbox1.text = advisorText
Textbox1.text = weightText
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Textbox1.text = advisorText + " " + weightText
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function GetData() As String
  Dim totalRecords As Integer = sqlTableInstitution.Rows.Count
  Dim advisorText As String = ""
  Dim weightText As String = ""
  Dim result As String
  If Not IsDBNull(sqlTableInstitution.Rows(0)("advisor_name")) Then
    advisorText = sqlTableInstitution.Rows(0)("advisor_name")
    If Not IsDBNull(sqlTableInstitution.Rows(0)("Influence_weight_name")) Then
      weightText = sqlTableInstitution.Rows(0)("Influence_weight_name")
      result = String.Format("{0}-{1}",advisorText, weightText)
    End If
  End If
  Return result
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you reach this line

```
Textbox1.text = weightText
```

you replace `Textbox1.Text` with `weightText` instead of concatenating it with `weightText`

Try to replace the following code

```
Textbox1.text = advisorText
Textbox1.text = weightText
```

with this code

```
Textbox1.Text = advisorText & weightText
```